# Why is my Python program not finding the difference between the two sets?

Tags: python, set

I'm able to successfully get all the IP addresses on my wifi and I'm storing them in a knownIP list. Then I'm testing it by accessing the WiFi network with my iPhone. The second scan successfully detects and adds the new IP to a list. I make both of the lists a set and then use the difference. But it's only printing set() and it's an empty set.

```py
# print statements are added for troubleshooting purposes
knownIPlist = initial_scan()
print(knownIPlist)
knownIPList_set = set(knownIPlist)
scanWifi = True
while scanWifi:
    print("Turn on iPhone") 
    time.sleep(15)
    print("Scanning...")
    scanIPlist = scan()
    print(scanIPlist)
    scanIPlist_set = set(scanIPlist)
    newIPlist = knownIPList_set.difference(scanIPlist_set)
    print(newIPlist)
    # for newIP in newIPlist:
    #    print(newIP)
    print("waiting...")
```

The output is:

```
'192.168.1.64', '192.168.1.77', '192.168.1.190', '192.168.1.208', '192.168.1.216', '192.168.1.217', '192.168.1.220', '192.168.1.222', '192.168.1.227', '192.168.1.254', '192.168.1.66'

Turn on iPhone

Scanning...
'192.168.1.64', '192.168.1.77', '192.168.1.190', '192.168.1.208', '192.168.1.210', '192.168.1.216', '192.168.1.217', '192.168.1.220', '192.168.1.222', '192.168.1.227', '192.168.1.254', '192.168.1.66'

set()

waiting...
```

It successfully finds the new IP address (.210) in the new scan but it just prints out "set ()". It's just an empty set. Why is it not adding and printing the new .210 IP address to the newIPlist?

Answer (score 1):

[`set.difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference) returns the elements in the left hand `set` that aren't in the right hand `set`. Adding elements to the right hand set can only reduce the number of elements in the result, not add to it. As written, you'll report IPs that have *disappeared* since the original `set` was created, not *new* IPs that have *appeared* since then.

To report only new IPs, reverse the call:

```
newIPlist = scanIPlist_set.difference(knownIPList_set)
```

Or for brevity (and to make it clearer that you're taking away the elements from one, where the named `difference` method is less clear, and likely the source of your confusion):

```
newIPlist = scanIPlist_set - knownIPList_set
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I tried that before posting and it didn't work. Another commenter below said to see if I did == and print True and it indeed printed true despite having one more IP address? Any ideas why that may be?

Comment: @BrandonJacobson: It definitely wouldn't behave that way with the output you describe; `192.168.1.210` is in one, but not the other. So you're omitting something, and/or the behavior you describe isn't reproducible because the IPs aren't the same in your current run. Given you're scanning for IPs on the network, rerunning the same script after the new IP is in place would not produce a difference; are you sure the IP isn't there at the start, and appears later? I'm guessing in your second run the iPhone already had an IP assigned from the start.

Comment: What does `type(scanIPList)` return? I'll bet it's not really a list, it's a generator of some kind. Then `print(scanIPList)` is using up the generator, so `set(ScanIPList)` creates an empty set.

Answer (score 1):

`knownIPList_set.difference(scanIPlist_set)` returns all the elements of `knownIPList_set` that aren't in `scanIPlist_set`. The `.210` IP is in `scanIPlist_set`, but not `knownIPList_set`. So you need to reverse the operation:

```
newIPlist = scanIPlist_set.difference(knownIPList_set)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and the editing change! I didn't know the output should be in a code block. I tried changing the order before posting and it didn't work. Another commenter below said to see if I did == and print True and it indeed printed true despite having one more IP address? Any ideas why that may be?

Answer (score 0):

Both the set contains same elements, so when you take the difference, it will result in the empty set and hence it is printing set().

Try printing,

```
if(knownIPList_set == scanIPlist_set):
    print("True")
```

Comment: So I did this and it indeed printed true. How is that possible? There are 9 IPs in the knownIP list and then 10 IPs in the scanIPlist but it's still true?

Comment: Where do you get the idea they have the same elements? `192.168.1.210` is in the latter output, but not the former.

Comment: That's why I'm confused, but he was right that it still prints true.

Comment: A comment above made me realize something is wrong with the knownIPlist_set. When I print that out, it looks like this: 
{'4', '2', '9', "'", '0', '5', '1', '.', '8', '6', '7', ',', ' '}
I'll have to troubleshoot what's wrong with the sets.

Answer (score 0):

@Brandon

You're trying the reverse that is why you are getting an empty set. To figure out, please run the below snippet:

```
knownIPList_set = {'192.168.1.64', '192.168.1.77', '192.168.1.190', '192.168.1.208', '192.168.1.216', '192.168.1.217', '192.168.1.220', '192.168.1.222', '192.168.1.227', '192.168.1.254', '192.168.1.66'}
scanIPlist_set = {'192.168.1.64', '192.168.1.77', '192.168.1.190', '192.168.1.208', '192.168.1.210', '192.168.1.216', '192.168.1.217', '192.168.1.220', '192.168.1.222', '192.168.1.227', '192.168.1.254', '192.168.1.66'}

newIPlist_incorrect = knownIPList_set.difference(scanIPlist_set)
print(newIPlist_incorrect)


newIPlist_correct = scanIPlist_set.difference(knownIPList_set)
print(newIPlist_correct)
```

The output will be as following:

```
set()
{'192.168.1.210'}
```

I hope it gives an idea of what is not right in your code. You should be subtracting knownIPList_set from scanIPlist_set. That's it.

Comment: When I run this code in a separate file it works perfectly. Do you think there's something wrong with the structure of the lists I'm putting into sets?

Comment: your code is correct, @BrandonJacobson . Just change one line of code. newIPlist = knownIPList_set.difference(scanIPlist_set) TO newIPlist = scanIPlist_set.difference(knownIPList_set)

Comment: No, there's something wrong. Your suggestion gave me the idea to print out the actual knownIPList_set and it prints out this:
{'4', '2', '9', "'", '0', '5', '1', '.', '8', '6', '7', ',', ' '}
I'll have to troubleshoot what's wrong with the lists. Thank you for giving me this idea.

Comment: that's great that you figured out the root cause. You're welcome!!

Comment: Any idea why converting the list to a set is messing it up?

Comment: I can not able to think of any scenario where converting the list to a set can cause any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for all your recommendations.

The problem was in the code prior to my questions. The knownIPlist and scanIPlist were type strings, so when I declared them as sets it was giving this output:

```py
{'4', '2', '9', "'", '0', '5', '1', '.', '8', '6', '7', ',', ' '}
```

instead of the IPs, so comparing them wasn't doing anything. Also, this was the correct order to get the output of my iPhone joining my wifi.

```py
newIPlist = scanIPlist_set.difference(knownIPList_set)
```